# Sencha app packaging to desktop application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I developed a sencha app and ported it to IOS and Android successfully.I need to build a desktop application from the same.I used sencha's packager and it was a success.Unfortunately it was a trial version.

I used Tide SDK but the sencha list UI is not perfect on scrolling.And store data is not getting sometime.

Can anyone suggest other opensource packagers to make my sencha app to desktop application.

Pls help me.I was looking this for long time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try intel's node-webkit, it is one of the other tools that people are switching to. it's open source.

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, try out Brackets shell. We use that to create desktop apps on Mac and Windows. The wiki explains how to build your apps nice and simple

https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell

https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell

have fun